# How to shift 111 starting with 00000001 Assembler

Tags: assembly, byte, bit, avr, shift

I need to shift value of register in a loop. I need to start with a `00000001 -> 00000011 -> 00000111 -> 00001110 -> 00011100 -> 00111000 -> 01110000 -> 11100000 -> 01110000  -> 00111000-> 00011100-> 00001110-> 00000111 -> 00000011 -> 00000001 .`

I have no idea how to do this in the loop without hardcoding, maybe someone good at assembler can suggest how to perform such shifting elegantly.
Thx in advance

Comment: That looks like a nightmare to capture in formulas. Solution: lookup table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a trivial 16 bit rotation, the only complication is that it needs to reverse direction at both ends. Here is what I quickly put together:

```
    rcall init
loop:
    rcall next
    rjmp loop
init:
    ldi r16, 1    ; output
    ldi r17, 0xc0 ; buffer
    ldi r18, 0    ; direction
    ret
next:
    cpi r18, 0
    brne right
left:
    cpi r16, 0xe0
    breq right    ; go right if at the end
    ldi r18, 0    ; direction is left
    lsl r17       ; 16 bit rotate left
    rol r16
    ret
right:
    cpi r16, 1
    breq left
    ldi r18, 1    ; direction is right
    lsr r16       ; 16 bit rotate right
    ror r17
    ret
```